# Audio is muted after 15-30 minutes of listening to youtube

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, mute

This one really drives me crazy. Every time I listen music on youtube on my laptop with headsets it somehow gets muted after 15-30 minutes. If I unmute it through the sound control icon in the status bar, it will be muted again in a few seconds. Sometimes changing a track helps me to get another few minutes of uninterrupted audio.

I'm using Win 10, Chrome 58.0.3029.81. I suspect there is a SW that tries to prevent me from long listening period either by monitoring my audio activities, but I can't find anything suspicious in the list of startup/services. Or may be it's something else.

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

Found it:

- My company policies require periodic security checks on my laptop
- The installed audio driver requires a security update (Really?)
  **- an automatic silent update fails to update the driver**
- The security checking tool disables the Audio device as not compliant with security policies

Need to find the way to patch the driver.